# How to select bunch of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with multiple columns , i want to select bunch of rows if column B have consecutive 1 and check in these rows if column A have any value equal to 0.04 then need  this bunch of rows and extract start value and end value of column A for this bunch of rows

Here is my dataframe
[image]

Here is my desired output:

[image]

Comment: please paste the text than to show images, it would be easy for others give answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**filtter** Consecutive groups `.diff().abs().cumsum().bfill()` not following the specific considitons `(x['B'].eq(1).any() and x['A'].eq(0.04).any()`

**agg** first and last

followed by grouping consecutivity column to extract first and last rows with use of agg fun

```
df['temp'] = df.B.diff().abs().cumsum().bfill()
df.groupby('temp').filter(lambda x: (x['B'].eq(1).any() and x['A'].eq(0.04).any()))\
    .groupby('temp').agg({'A':['first','last']})
```

Out:

```
A
first   last
temp        
3.0 344.0   39.9
```